# What does `NO-CARRIER` and `DOWN` mean for a wireless interface?

Tags: debian, networking

I have a remote server and I log output of certain commands while the server cannot access the internet.

It uses a wireless interface to connect to the internet.

In a working state the output of `ip link list` shows:

```
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT qlen 1000 link/ether 00:13:ef:b0:29:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

When it is not working the output of `ip link list` shows:

```
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT qlen 1000 link/ether 00:13:ef:b0:29:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What does this `NO-CARRIER` and `DOWN` mean for a wireless interface? In the case of ethernet, this would mean that the cable is disconnected.

I would also appreciate any advice as to how I can further debug why the connection was not working. I also do a `wicd-cli -y -l` scan during the outage and it appears that the access point is still broadcasting. I cannot find any other hardware or software errors in the kernel messages.

Comment: It means the same thing as it does for a wired interface: you're disconnected.

Comment: @psusi Is there some documentation that tells that and could you share it please.

Comment: I wouldn't think you would need explicit instructions that the meaning you already established for that flag didn't change to something completely different just because you're using a wireless adapter.

Answer (score 8):

There is no document that would tell you what specially means for wireless. If your wifi is `UP` and `NO-CARRIER` means that is administratively up(`ip link set dev wlan0 up`) but not associated and authenticated with a SSID. Only `LOWER_UP` means that link layer is operational.

`ip link list wlan0` and `iw wlan0 link` are 2 ways to retrieve link status information. The second form will show you if associated with a SSID, and show relevant wireless information.

Probably the cause of your link problems are related with Wireless power saving configurations, and thus the `DORMANT`state of your interface.

Netlink interface [flags](https://www.infradead.org/~tgr/libnl/doc/route.html):

> IFF_DORMANT - Driver signals dormant

Check out the links below with instructions on how to chance this behavior.

**Additional Documentation:**

- [Power Management on Network Interfaces](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Network_interfaces)
- [How to Connect WIFI using cli](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com.br/2013/10/how-to-connect-to-wpawpa2-wifi-network.html) - Take a look at some of the outputs.